# EPiserver cache load balancer

Tags: caching, load, load-balancing, episerver

I have a strange problem with EpiServer 6.0 . When it is on the environment behind the load 
balancer it seems to have out dated cache. For example when accessing user settings it doesn't bring the latest data however when run locally or when load balancer is not present I got the latest results. There is an event listener set-up between the two load balanced servers to update the cache. Could anybody advise please?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-6/EPiServer-CMS-60/Event-Management-System-Specification/) article will probably be helpful to you.

First thing to check is that the enableEvents and enableRemoteEvents attributes are both set to “true” in the episerver.config file

Comment: Perhaps a firewall issue blocking UDP traffic between the servers?

Comment: No I checked the firewall :/  also it seems that this is happening only for a custom attribute on a user,  pages are updating fine

Comment: What about EPiServer log files when enabling logging? One more additional question -> by accessing user settings you mean in CMS?